# How to make text of checkbox toggle as well

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, checkbox

I have checkbox and text 'click me'.
I did not use any external library for checkbox.

```
<TouchableOpacity
          onPress={onPress}
      >
        {isSelected && (
            <Icon
                color={Colors.darkPurple}
            />
        )}
      </TouchableOpacity>
```

And import this component into another one adding text (I mean title for checkbox)

```
        <View>
              <CheckBox
                style={styles.checkBox}
                touchableProps={{ onPress: this.toggle }}
              />
              <Text>click me</Text>
            </View>
```

The issue is that the only checkbox icon is clickable. I need to make title of checkbox be clickable as well.

React Native.

Comment: Wrap the `<CheckBox>` component in a `<label>` element?

Answer (score 0):

You should make the title part of the Checkbox component itself. For example, you could pass the title as children:

```
<Checkbox>
  click me
</Checkbox>
```

Inside your component definition, place the Text within the TouchableOpacity:

```
<TouchableOpacity>
  <Icon />
  <Text>{this.props.children}</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Some parts of the code above were omitted to get to the point.